# Implement real cascading or child selectors for CSS in AS3

Tags: css, actionscript-3

We all know there's CSS support in AS3. But actually it's not CSS, but just SS. Is there a way to implement cascading?

For example I have

```
Compare <em>regular italic</em> and <strong>bold text or event <em>bold italic.</em></strong>
```

How can I define special fonts for regular italic and strong italic?

upd: or how is it named? Basically "How to make styles for child selectors work?"

Comment: I think you might be confusing cascading with inheritance.

Answer (score -1):

I'f you're using Flex an upgrade to flex 4 will solve it. 
https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-14385

If you're using Flash, no idea!

Comment: That is CSS for Flex components, I was talking about html text.